# How to secure hundreds of AES keys

Tags: cryptography, hsm

I need to store a large amount of AES keys and provide an API to decrypt user-provided ciphertext.

The application flow is as follows:

1. The user authenticates
2. The user makes a POST request with some cyphertext and a MAC signature (cleartext encrypted and signed with the same AES key stored on the server)
3. The API responds with cleartext and an integrity flag (true/false)

Here are some constraints:

- The service is hosted on a Kubernetes cluster
- The user's AES key must not be tied to the user's credentials (the API key must not be used to encrypt the AES key)

My questions are:

- What is the best way to secure the AES keys server-side?
  Storing plain-text keys in a SQL DB does not seem like a good choice to me.
- Is there a way to use an HSM to decrypt data directly without ever exposing the user's AES key to the application?
- What is the best method to protect these keys WITHOUT an HSM?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm missing the broader picture here, i.e. the actual real-world use case behind this requirement. The keys must come from somewhere, the data encrypted using these keys most come from somewhere ..  - is key generation and encryption done on the same system or where? Is it really necessary to store the AES keys instead of using hybrid encryption with asymmetric user specific keys? What is the threat scenario, i.e. what attackers with what capabilities you need to fight, what are the values behind the encrypted data you need protect.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the AES key is generated externally and stored on the "cloud" AND on a user device which is used to encrypt the plaintext. The user can then decrypt and verify the ciphertext via the API without the aforementioned device.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of an HSM is to protect the keys (rule 1)

The purpose of a Key Management System is to manage the keys.

You are positing a RESTful server that will,

1. Authenticate a user. If valid, continue. If not, decline to continue.
2. Accept a {payload}+MAC
3. Based on the user's credentials, select one or more keys *handles* (using a key management system)
4. Using its own credentials with the HSM, pass the payload and MAC and key handles to the HSM.  The HSM will resolve the key handles, then use one key to decrypt the payload, and use the second key to validate the [C|H]MAC.  HSM discards the keys (zeroization) and returns the results. Notes: 2 keys.  Not recommended to use the same key for encryption and for authentication. Also, "key handles" assumes that the keys are stored internally in the HSM. Some HSMs either require or allow external keys, in which case the key isn't a handle, it's an encrypted key blob.
5. Server takes responses and returns them to caller over TLS.

In an HSM-based system, the actual key is never available (in plain) to anything other than the secure memory of the HSM itself.

There are servers/applications/etc that will provide this service, or you can write your own.

I've implemented the above as a PoC.  For me, the tricky bit was #1, authenticate the user -- I'm an HSM guy, not a Quarkus/MTLS expert.

We stored the key blobs externally, in a Postgre RDBMS.  We didn't use the user's credentials to access the key blob directly, rather we used the user's credentials and a token that had access control and a policy engine around it -- the User needed to log in correctly, from the correct IP address, M-F from 5am to 6pm in the server's timezone, and also the token had to relate to one of "their" key sets (a given user could have multiple key sets).

Unfortunately, I don't feel qualified to answer the "how to WITHOUT an HSM", because I work for a company that makes HSMs, so I'm biased :)

Comment: I guess you can do similar things with OS backed keystores, smart cards, TPM's etc. I've actually designed a PKCS#11 interface that used a smart card once for a specific key management requirement. Not sure if it ever got used in the end, but it was there.